# session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Esto me da estos dos errores:  **session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent, Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.**

Estoy tratando de hacer un login, tengo todo sobre la conexión bien pero no entiendo bien estos problemas porque se pueden causar, pero me salen estos errores que no entiendo la razón de ellos, cuando quito la parte de  `session_start():` igualmente me da el error del header, agradecería que alguien me ayudara con este problema.

ingreso.php (Codigo del login) es donde tengo el SELECT conectandolo con ingreso.php (Codigo del formulario) que este seria de la pagina de ingreso.

Este es mi código:

````
Conex.php
<?php 
// Defino las constantes de conexion=+
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$basedatos="programming_for_all"; //Aqui coloco el nombre de la base de datos de mi proyecto
$pass="";
$msj="No se ha encontrado enlace con el servidor o la base de datos";

//Constructor de conexion, utilizamos el mètodo mysqli() para realizar la conexiòn 
$conexion= new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$basedatos) or die ($msj);

$acento= $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//Si no se puede conectar, envìa un mensaje de error 
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
}
 ?>

ingreso.php (Codigo del login) 

<?php
include("../Modelo/conex.php");

$NAME = $_POST['name'];
$LASTNAME = $_POST['lastname'];
$EMAIL = $_POST['email'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=$NAME;

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Nombre_us='$NAME' & Apellido_us='$LASTNAME' & Correo_us='$EMAIL' & Clave_us='$PASSWORD'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($filas){
    
    header("location:../../Vista/index.php");

} else {
    ?>
    <?php
    header("location:../../Vista/registro.php");
    ?>
    <h1>ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACIÓN</h1>
    <?php
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conexion); ```



ingreso.php (Codigo del formulario)
<div class="box-ingreso">
<div class="ingreso-box">
    <img class="logo" src="../vista/assets/media/img/Website logone.jfif" alt="Logo de progamacion">
    <h1>Ingresa aquí</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <!--Usuario-->
        <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input class="Nombre"  name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
        <!---->
        <!--Usuario-->
        <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input class="Apellido"  name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido">
        <!---->
        <!--Correo-->
        <label for="Correo">Correo</label>
        <input class="Correo"  name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electronico">
        <!---->   
        <!--Contraseña-->
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input class="contraseña" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
        <!---->
       <center><button type="Submit" class="submit" name="login">Ingresar</button></center> 
                
        <a href="">¿Ha olvidado su contraseña?</a><br>
        <a href="../vista/registro.php">Registrarse</a>
    </form>
    <?php
      include('../vista/assets/datos/ingreso.php');
    ?>
</div>
</div>`
````

Comment: Lo que dice el mensaje es que las cabeceras (header) ya fueron enviadas, cosa que no debe ocurrir antes de iniciar la sesión. Puede que en algunos de tus archivos o en tu contenido que está antes de iniciar la sesión haya alguna salida por pantalla que estaría en consecuencia enviando las cabeceras. ¿Qué significa esto al inicio del código que nos muestras en la pregunta: `ingreso.php (Codigo de conexión)`?

Comment: Lo puse porque los dos se llaman ```ingreso.php```

Comment: Coloca output_buffering = 8192 en tu php.ini.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Significa que los archivos donde está ese código se llaman `ingreso.php`? Es confuso como lo tienes en la pregunta, porque se ve como si fuese parte del código. Por otra parte, muéstranos lo que hay en el archivo que incluyes al principio: `conex.php`

Comment: Ya puse lo que hay en `conex.php`, Si los archivos se llaman `ingreso.php`

Comment: Si estás trabajando con sesiones y con header, no debes poner ninguna salida en los otros archivos. Por ejemplo, si la conexión falla, esto saldrá por pantalla: `echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();` y cuando eso ocurra las cabeceras serán enviadas. No sé si será exactamente el caso, pero es lo único que se ve, en el flujo que muestras, que podría estar rompiendo el código. Quita ese `echo` y en tus archivos `ingreso.php` considera verificar la conexión ante todo con un `if ($conexion) { //aquí todo el código } else { //no hay conexión, actuar en consecuencia }`

Comment: Si no estoy usando echo, ¿Que hago en ese caso?

Comment: Le quite los header y le puse mejor h1 para saber cuando si coge los datos sin el error del header, pero sigo con este error session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in

Comment: Como te dije más arriba, debes controlar las salidas por pantalla cuando trabajas con sesiones. Siguiendo el esquema del `if` que te indiqué más arriba, prueba a poner algo así en la parte del `else`, para probar si tu problema es la conexión: `} else { echo "No hay conexión"; }` Para depurar todo el flujo de tu código puedes comentar todos los `header` y poner un `echo`, así sabrás por dónde está entrando el código.